# Menu of sites in multidomain Neos

Tags: neoscms

In TYPO3 Neos, how can I build a menu containing the list of sites available? If I use `entryLevel = 0`, I get the list of pages under the current site.

Answer (score 0):

not with the normal "Menu" so much I can say. It was intended to be used inside a site. I have no obvious solution for you right now, but will check back. You probably *could* create a little plugin fetching the site and domain records from their repositories and creating a menu from that.